# How to make KAZE features detect corners?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-detection, sift, corner-detection

I'm struggling to control the interest points in KAZE detector. I only want the detector to extract the corner/interest points. What parameters do I tweak to get the desired results?

This is my code:

```
img = imread("")
I = rgb2gray(img);

points = detectKAZEFeatures(I,'NumOctaves', 3, 'NumScaleLevels', 4); 
num_points = length(points); 

figure;
imshow(bilde_gray); 
hold on;
plot(points.selectStrongest(num_points);
```

[image]

Comment: How should we know if there is no example (image) where to show what is needed and what goes wrong? Not so flex missing that information... (update with info by editing question is aloud)

Comment: Sorry about that. I have attached the image now